# Terragrunt state file keeps overriding

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt

I am using terragrunt with following structure:

```
├── env
│   ├── prod
│   └── dev
│       ├── IAM
│       │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│       ├── S3
│       │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│       └── account.hcl
├── src
│   ├── IAM
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   └── S3
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── variables.tf
├── terragrunt.hcl
```

root terragrunt.hcl:

```
locals {
  account_vars = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("account.hcl"))
  aws_profile = local.account_vars.locals.aws_profile_name
}
terraform {
  extra_arguments "aws_profile" {
    commands = [
      "init",
      "apply",
      "refresh",
      "import",
      "plan",
      "destroy"
    ]
    env_vars = {
      AWS_PROFILE = "${local.aws_profile}"
    }
  }
}

remote_state {
  backend = "local"
  config = {
    path = "${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/${local.aws_profile}-terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

generate "provider" {
  path      = "provider.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite"
  contents = <<EOF
provider "aws" {
  region              = "eu-central-1"
  profile = "${local.aws_profile}"
     default_tags {
       tags = {
        <tag1>
        <tag2>
        }
     }
}
EOF
}
```

I have clean AWS account without zero resources created yet.

When I run `terragrunt apply` from dev/IAM directory, it creates the resources.

When I switch to dev/S3 and run`terragrunt apply`, it wants to destroy all the IAM resources and create S3 resources after that. Looks like each module is writing its own state file, overriding the one created before.

Do you have any ideas why is this happening like that?

Tried to use several configuration variations, same results all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You parent terragrunt file setup is not correct. Currently you are using `get_parent_terragrunt_dir()` which will be returning the dir where the parent `terragrunt.hcl` runs. This means that when you run your sub dirs they will end up with the same state file since both sub dirs will have the same parent dir. Instead you should be using `path_relative_to_include()` which will be the path from your parent to the sub dir. Essentially you should see https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-remote-state-configuration-dry/#filling-in-remote-state-settings-with-terragrunt

```
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "my-terraform-state"
    key            = "${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    encrypt        = true
    dynamodb_table = "my-lock-table"
  }
```

Comment: also i dont beleive path is an attribute or remote_state

Comment: I'd suggest only changing the region in the `backend` block to be `"eu-central-1"` instead of `"us-east-1"`.

Comment: Yeah @MarkoE this is just the example from terragrunt docs